# How to store links for selected images from an array to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to store selected images by storing their index in the array. Once the index of the selected images is saved, and the button (get item (with the id of "done") is clicked, I need to stringify the url of the images selected in the array so to store them in the localstorage. Then I need to extract the data from the localstorage and convert it back to an object, write the selected images on the page, and import the selected images from the local storage on the page. The page should work if changes are made to the length of the array.

Also, I need to use the checkbox to select or deselect the item, but at the moment it's only working when I click on the image.

Thank you! Please only javascript

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
        img.selected {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="vegetable()">
        <button id="done" onclick="new()">get item </button>
        <div id="idmain"></div>
        <script>
        function new() {}
        var hey = [
            { item: "knife", fruit: "banana.png" },
            { item: "fork", fruit: "apple.png" },
            { item: "sword", fruit: "kiwi.jpg" },
            { item: "spoon", fruit: "mango.jpg" }
        ];

        function vegetable() {
            for (var i = 0; i < hey.length; i++) {
                var Img = document.createElement("img");
                Img.setAttribute("src", hey[i].fruit);
                Img.setAttribute("class", "posterImage");

                var Div = document.createElement("div");
                Div.setAttribute("class", "posterDiv");
                Img.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    if (this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                        this.className = "posterImage unselected";
                        this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked =
                            false;
                    } else {
                        this.className = "posterImage selected";
                        this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked =
                            true;
                    }
                });
                Div.appendChild(Img);
                var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
                newCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                Div.appendChild(newCheckbox);
                document.getElementById("idmain").appendChild(Div);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not related to your question but avoid naming your function `new` as its a reserved keyword.

Comment: If you only store an index and the array length changes the stored ones may not match any more. Suggest you create a different array for selected ones that you can copy the selected objects to and store that whole array. An array can be stored by using JSON.stringify() and then parsed from string using JSON.parse()